# Binding Combobox inside a Listview to a ObservableCollection<string>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="PatientsInscrit_GMF.ListDisplay"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:PatientsInscrit_GMF"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name ="FileList">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Tag" Width="Auto">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ></ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>   
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

.CS

```
namespace PatientsInscrit_GMF
{
    public partial class ListDisplay : UserControl
    {
        private ObservableCollection<string> _tags;

        public ObservableCollection<string> Tags
        {
            get { return _tags; }
        }

        public ListDisplay()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _tags = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            List<string> tags = Facade.Instance.RetrieveTags();
            foreach(string s in tags)
            {
                _tags.Add(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I BIND Tags to my Combobox, which is one of many columns in my Listview?

I tried

```
ItemsSource = "{Binding Tags}"
```

But The combobox remains empty. I know for sure the Facade List retrieve is not empty as when it's created I add 2 default tags so that it's not empty.

I have tried various other solutions that I found and none were working, there is even code samples that would not even compile.

Please help :)

Comment: Not sure I follow you?  ItemsSource= {binding ...} thats the binding? As I said I tried multiple solution, the XAML I posted is the  clean state in wich i need to add the binding. you should atleast read all of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that at the time (initially) the `Tags` property is fetched, the `_tags` has not been initialized. After `_tags` is initialized, you can raise the `Tags` property change (by implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`). However that property seems just need to be  initialized (changed) once. So implementing such interface is not really necessary. You can try the following code to ensure that at the time `Tags` is fetched, the data will be initialized:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Tags {
   get { 
      if(_tags == null){
        //move your code after InitializeComponent() to here
        _tags = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        List<string> tags = Facade.Instance.RetrieveTags();
        foreach(string s in tags) {
            _tags.Add(s);
        }
      }
      return _tags;
   }
}
```

In XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Tags,
          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"></ComboBox>
```

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is defaulty implemented in ObservableCollection (microsoft class) so I don't have to do that. I tried your solution and I still do not have anything inside my combobox. Yet I'll keep the idea of Lazy instantiation for that Object :)

Comment: @Fawar not sure why it does not work. But you misunderstood what I said here. I don't mean the `ObservableCollection`, I mean your class ***ListDisplay***. How could you misunderstand like that? `Tags` is a property of that class, right? raising property change for `Tags` means you have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your class

Comment: List Display is the CS of the XAMl, if it's not load at the time of the XAML, there is a massive problem in the WPF framework ;)

Comment: @Fawar it does not really matter, but keeping it is OK.

Comment: it worked! :D

Will that way of coding it make it updatable if I changed the items in my ObservableCollection? or is it Staticly Binded?


Tyvm

Comment: @Fawar I think it's OK because `ObservableCollection` implements both `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to DataBind please follow the following:

1) Make sure you have set your DataContext (in the UserControl tag) to `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

2) You need to change the ItemsSource binding in your ComboBox to: `ItemsSource="{Binding SomePropertyName}"`

3) You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged' in the backing cs file

4) To implement this property use the following:

```
    #region INotifyPorpertyChanged Memebers 

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
```

5) Make an property of type `ObservableCollection` of the type of object you want. This property is the property the ComboBoxis bounded to.

ex:

```
private ObservableCollection<SomeDataType> _myPrivateData;
public ObservableCollection<SomeDataType> SomePropertyName { get { return _myPrivateData; } set    { _myPrivateData= value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SomePropertyName"); } }
```

That takes care of the data binding part. Now every time you reset the collection that DataGrid is bound to your DataGrid will update because the NotifyPropertyChanged is called.

Comment: I tried this. It didn't worked.  Plus, ObersableCollection<T> is a microsoft class that is to be used in binding process as it implements the PropertyChangedEvent. So all i had to do to test your solution was to add the DataContext. I still ended up with an empty combobox.

Comment: So did you implement INotifyPropertychanged?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

Just go and read this, it's already in

Comment: Yes, but to update the UI you need to implement the interface so that you only set the DataContext once.